# Mixing input from mic and external mp3 in Android

Tags: android, audio, android-audiorecord

I just started learning android app development yesterday and wondering how to solve a rather non-trivial problem. What I'm trying to create is sort of a mini karaoke player, which lets the user record his song (mic source) along side a background song (external mp3 file). Another feature is to let the user hear himself while he sings - a *near realtime feedback*. In the end the recorded song, along with the background track should be mixed and stored in a file. To avoid devilish feedbacks, assume the user listens to the background track and himself on an headset.

What I was able to accomplish till now is to let the user record: `AudioRecord` with `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC` and send the buffers read directly into an instance of:
`AudioTrack` with `AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM`. I also keep persisting the buffers to a file, resulting in a raw PCM file.

It basically looks something like this:

```
    this.isPlaying = true;
    this.record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, this.bufferSize);

    this.track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM,
                SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, this.bufferSize,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        //..Some customizations with this.track, etc...


    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(audiofile.getPath());

    this.record.startRecording();
    this.track.play();

    while (isPlaying) {

        this.record.read(buffer, 0, this.bufferSize);
        fout.write(buffer);
        this.track.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    }

    fout.close();
```

The method is run in a separate thread and everything is good so far. What I'm having a hard time figuring out is playing a separate background track and mixing them into one stream. I'm aware that mixing is just additive and straightforward when two raw data are similar (channels, sampling frequency etc). So one possible solution might be to convert an MP3 file to raw PCM with same features, playing that in a separate audio track and later mixing them. But I suspect some terrible sync issue here due to the heavy latencies involved. I'm not even sure if this is the right way to go forward. Is there a simpler and more elegant solution? What android libraries would you suggest to perform the conversion?

Comment: github then search "audio mixer"

Comment: Just "audio mixer" does not help, because I wanna do this in Android. Rather I had searched for "android audio" earlier and it did not help me out much - too many results and not very specific to this problem.

Comment: http://mobilengineering.blogspot.com/2012/06/audio-mix-and-record-in-android.html have you looked for implementations of android codecs to use with "AudioRecord" where you can just feed 2 channels to the codec and to have the encode operation merge them? ive not done that so dont know if it works but have seen the low-level codec code that would seem to permit that type operation.